# Measure MySQL database performance during design

Tags: php, mysql, simulation

I always wonder if there is any mechanism to measure performance of a MySQL database before going in to production with different data loads and queries.

In other words, let's say I have designed a database for one of my project. 
At this database design phase I want to check if my schema is optimized or what would be the performance of different queries on this structure.

Comment: There's no automated tool to do that (as far as I know). You need to write queries on your own and run them to see how they perform with different amount of data and under different load. This is usually done using programs via CLI interface since it's easier to run such programs.

Comment: With a small amount of data, a missing INDEX will go unnoticed.  With a small amount of data, everything can be cached, so you won't notice things that are inherently I/O-bound.  Etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP debugbar. This way, you can look at your queries and see how much time they take, so you can optimize them even further if need be.
Have a look here: [PHP Debugbar](http://phpdebugbar.com/)

Comment: My question is before going into code development validate database schema.